# Getting Firefox undecorated

Tags: firefox

I am currently developing a Firefox addon which shows content that is remotely sent to Firefox.

My main problem is, to get Firefox into an undecorated mode so only the content is shown on the screen. Also it must be possible to resize, move and pin the window on top. Moreover it should work platform indepentend.

I already tried "R-Kiosk", but "R-Kiosk" starts Firefox only in fullscreen.

Is there any extension or workaround available to solve this problem?

Comment: _“but "R-Kiosk" starts Firefox only in fullscreen.”_ – not sure if at all possible, but have you tried resizing the window via JS after opening in fullscreen?

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
<applications>
   <application name="firefox-bin">
   <decor>no</decor>
   <application>

</applications>
```

Comment: I know that this is an old question but would you mind explaining your answer? I am having the same issue and your answer is not very helpful...